# Percentage Greater than/Less than in a table

Tags: excel

I have a table that I want to find the percentage greater than and percentage less than compared to a baseline, for the total group based on the weights of each group.

Here is my example table:

```
    Benchmark   GRP 1   GRP 2   GRP 3   GRP 4
    10          10       11      10      12
    14          12       15      11      15
    17          11       17      13      16
    18          14       15      14      17

    Poulation   40       45      30      80
```

What I want to do is find out for each level of the benchmark what % of the total population of all four groups is above or below the bench mark value.

I have tried various sumproducts and sumifs but can't seem to get it work.

Let me know your thoughts!

Thanks as always!

Comment: You probably want some variation on `=countif(_range,_ criteria)/count(range)` I am not totally clear on what you are testing in your example, but that is the structure I usually use for counting percent below or above a value.  (e.g.  `=countif(A1:A4,"<"&C8)/count(A1:A4)` will tell me the fraction of A1:A4 that are less than C8.)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your sample data is in A1:E7 put the following formula into B9 and use Ctrl+Shift+Enter to record it as an array formula:

`=SUM(IF(B$2:B$5>$A$2:$A$5,1,0))/COUNTA($A$2:$A$5)`

This can then be copied across under the other groups. Below is showing how it works for me.

Note: The array formula will display with braces ({...}) around it but you do not type these.

[image]